# Sql datetime format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime-format

My datetime that is stored in my DB, look like this:

```
2012-18-08 09:00:00
```

I want to get it in this format

```
dd.MM.yyyy - hh:mm

// expected output:
// 18.08.2012 - 09:00
```

How can I achieve that? Something like following

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Date,104) ??
```

I use MsSql 2008.

Comment: In SQL?If so, what database? If in an application, what platform/language are you using?

Comment: I don't want to be harsh, but: use Google first please.

Comment: Assuming SQL Server, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: What version of SQL Server? And do you really, definitely, absolutely *have* to do the formatting in the database end?

Comment: @Oded, I edited my question. Thanks for attentions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2008 and previous versions:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YourField,104) + '-' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),YourField,108)
```

For SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT FORMAT(YourField, 'dd.MM.yyyy - hh:mm')
```

Comment: Second field should be `VARCHAR(5)` or even `CHAR(5)`, but yeah, that's it

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables You are absolutely right. Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: [Date-Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),104) + ' - ' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),GETDATE(),108)
```

OUTPUT: `19.03.2013 - 18:35`

### [Live Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11219)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, there is a DATE_FORMAT() function (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

In your case, I would use:

```
DATE_FORMAT(`col`, "%d.%m.%Y - %H:%i");
```